# Nodejs getting all needed scripts and stylesheets route from a page request(without browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm wondering if it is possible for me to get all the scripts and stylesheets routes I need from a html file.(**not using browsers at all.**)

for example:

I run `index.html`, and the website need `./style.css` and also need `./script.js` and lot of images.

---

How could I know what `index.html` need the routes of `style.css` and `script.js` and images.

**another question:** Does the browser works like rendering HTML file while it need some files, the browser request to server and wait for response? So is there a way I could use nodejs to analog the action and not using browsers?

Comment: People that vote down the question, could tell me the reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out a good way to solve the problem is using phantomjs(http://phantomjs.org/), network-monitoring is probably something I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the location of your static content in your app.js file from where server will serve the files to browser when index.html will render.

```
for example if i have following directory structure

ROOT
 |
  ---public
 |     |
 |      ----css
 |     |     |
 |     |      ----style.css
 |     |     |
 |     |
 |      ----js
 |     |     |
 |     |      ----script.js
 |     |     |
 |     |
 |      ----images
 |     |
 |
 |
  ---app.js
 |
  ---index.html
 |

 Browser requested urls format are 
 css - > <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 js  - > <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

 after that you have to add following code in your app.js file;
```

> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

```
 if express is not installed in your system install it form cmd using command
```

> npm install express

```
 add following line of code in app.js
```

> var express = require('express')
>        , app = express();

Comment: Sorry, this is not the thing I'm looking for at all, I don't want to look for the routes via browser.